# (ngModelChange) works fine without adding [ngModel]?

Tags: angular, input, ngmodel

I used ngModelChange without ngModel in an input in a form , it works fine , it's not supposed to work though, any explanation  ?

the code

[image: 1]

i expected it won't work without the ngModel but it works fine

Comment: Please post code instead of images

Comment: you should use `(input)` HTML event. Be carefull, to get the value use $event.target

Comment: yes but here i dont wanna get the value , thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [formControlName Directive](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName)

It has a @Output('ngModelChange') update: EventEmitter
but its marked as deprecated since v6 so there is a chance it wont work with the next updateds.